# Two diagrams side by side

Tags: positioning, subfloats, feynmf

I am trying to put two feynman diagrams side by side, but they get displayed below eachother. I am using feynmf and subfloat. This normally works for pictures.

```
\begin{figure}[ht!]
      \centering
    \subfloat{

        \begin{fmfgraph*}(40, 25)
        \fmfstraight
         \fmfbottom{wm,i2,z2}
          \fmftop{wp,i1,z1}
          \fmf{dashes}{wp,i1,z1}
          \fmf{dashes}{z2,i2,wm}
          \fmf{dashes,caption=$W^{+}$}{i1,i2}
        %  \fmf{dashes,caption=$Z^0$}{i2,z1}
         % \fmf{dashes,caption=$Z^0$}{i2,z2}
        \fmfv{lab=$Z^0$}{z1}
        \fmfv{lab=$Z^0$}{z2}
    \fmfv{lab=$W^+$}{wp}
    \fmfv{lab=$W^-$}{wm}
        \end{fmfgraph*}
    }

    \subfloat{

        \begin{fmfgraph*}(40, 25)
        \fmfstraight
         \fmfbottom{wm,i2,z2}
          \fmftop{wp,i1,z1}
          \fmf{dashes}{wp,i1,z1}
          \fmf{dashes}{z2,i2,wm}
          \fmf{dashes,caption=$W^{+}$}{i1,i2}
        %  \fmf{dashes,caption=$Z^0$}{i2,z1}
         % \fmf{dashes,caption=$Z^0$}{i2,z2}
        \fmfv{lab=$Z^0$}{z1}
        \fmfv{lab=$Z^0$}{z2}
    \fmfv{lab=$W^+$}{wp}
    \fmfv{lab=$W^-$}{wm}
        \end{fmfgraph*}
    }

    \caption{Exchange of W boson}
    \end{figure}
```

Comment: Don't leave blank lines between the `\subfloat`s

Comment: I'd also recommend you provide a minimal example. A lot is not clear for people who never use `fmfgraph*`. For example, which packages should they include....

Comment: I didn't know that problem was unrelated to fmfgraph. I'll try and make better examples next time.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As @egreg said in the comments, the reason why the second figure is below is due to the blank line.

There is a very good reason for this. Recall that in text mode a blank line signals the beginning of a new paragraph and subsequent text is placed below.  So, the following will place the words next to each other:

```
One
Two
```

but the following will place the words below each other:

```
One

Two
```

Same goes for pictures, there are just *boxes* as far as `TeX` is concerned, not much different from letters, words, paragraphs, etc....

The MWE below produces the image on the left,
but if you insert a blank line you get the image on the right:

[image]
[image]

### Note:

- My rule of thumb is **not** to use blank lines unless I am trying to indicate a new paragraph. For readability you can insert a comment line as long as the first non-blank character is a `%`.  Note that it does not need to be at the beginning of the line as in the MWE below.

### Code:

Since this problem is not related to `feynmf`, I simply used `pgfplots` to generate the figures:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht!]
    \centering
    \subfloat{
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[height=3cm]
        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
    % A blank line here like a new paragraph so next picture is placed below
    \subfloat{
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[height=3cm]
        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }

    \caption{Exchange two subfloats}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```