# how to separate 3 tree latex

Tags: tikz-pgf, latex-project, tikz-trees

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Two diagrams side by side](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42270/two-diagrams-side-by-side)
>   [construction set of tree](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60577/construction-set-of-tree)

I have three trees in latex, I want to represent 2 like this and the third before both ?

```
\documentclass[openright,a4paper,11pt,french]{report}


\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt, node distance=2cm, on grid, auto,thick,initial text=]
   \node[state, initial,minimum size=3ex]            (0)                          {0};
   \node[state,minimum size=3ex]                     (1)   [above right =of 0]    {1};
   \node[state,minimum size=3ex]                     (2)   [right =of 0]          {2};
   \node[state,accepting,minimum size=3ex]           (3)   [right =of 2]          {3/0};



  \path[->]      (0)  edge         node           {a:a / 1.61}   (1)
                 (0)  edge        node           {b:b/ 0.22}   (2)
                  (1)  edge       node           {a:b/ 0}   (2)
                 (2)  edge [loop below]  node         {b:a/ 0.69}   ()
                 (2)  edge               node           {b:a/ 0.69}   (3);

\end{tikzpicture}   





\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt, node distance=2cm, on grid, auto,thick,initial text=,minimum size=0pt]
   \node[state, initial ,minimum size=3ex]            (0)                          {0};
   \node[state,minimum size=3ex]                     (1)   [right =of 0]          {1};
   \node[state,accepting,minimum size=3ex]           (2)   [right =of 1]          {2/0};




  \path[->]      (0)  edge     [loop above]   node           {a:a / 1.2}   ()
                 (0)  edge      [bend left]   node           {a:b/ 2.3}   (1)
                 (0)  edge      [bend right]   node           {b:a/ 0.51}   (1)
                 (1)  edge      [loop below]  node         {b:b/ 0.92}   ()
                 (1)  edge                    node           {a:a/ 0.51}   (2);

\end{tikzpicture}  


\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt, node distance=2cm, on grid, auto,thick,initial text=,minimum size=0pt]
   \node[state, initial,minimum size=3ex]            (0)                          {0};
   \node[state,minimum size=3ex]                     (1)   [above right =of 0]    {1};
   \node[state,minimum size=3ex]                     (2)   [right =of 0]          {4};
   \node[state,minimum size=3ex]                     (3)   [right =of 2]          {2};
   \node[state,minimum size=3ex,accepting]           (4)   [right =of 3]          {3/0};


\begin{scope}[every node/.style={scale=.7}]
  \path[->]      (0)  edge        node           {a:a / 2.81}   (1)
                 (0)  edge        node           {a:b / 3.91}   (2)
                 (0)  edge     [bend right]   node           {b:a / 0.73}   (3)
                (1)  edge        node           {a:a / 0.51}   (3)
                (2)  edge        node           {a:b / 0.92}   (3)
                (3)  edge       node          {b:a / 1.2}   (4);


  \end{scope}


\end{tikzpicture}   

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is quite likely a duplicate of [Two diagrams side by side](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42270/2693).  Also there are various other similar questions on the site: search for 'side by side'.

Comment: This is also an exact duplicate of a question by you: [Construction set of trees](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/60577/2693) and you have accepted this answer.