# construction set of tree

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees

I have three trees in latex , I have this construction :

[image]

with his code :

```
\documentclass[openright,a4paper,11pt,french]{report}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt, node distance=2cm, on grid, auto,thick,initial text=]
   \node[state, initial,minimum size=3ex]            (0)                          {0};
   \node[state,minimum size=3ex]                     (1)   [above right =of 0]    {1};
   \node[state,minimum size=3ex]                     (2)   [right =of 0]          {2};
   \node[state,accepting,minimum size=3ex]           (3)   [right =of 2]          {3/0};



  \path[->]      (0)  edge         node           {a:a / 1.61}   (1)
                 (0)  edge        node           {b:b/ 0.22}   (2)
                  (1)  edge       node           {a:b/ 0}   (2)
                 (2)  edge [loop below]  node         {b:a/ 0.69}   ()
                 (2)  edge               node           {b:a/ 0.69}   (3);

\end{tikzpicture}   

\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt, node distance=2cm, on grid, auto,thick,initial text=,minimum size=0pt]
   \node[state, initial ,minimum size=3ex]            (0)                          {0};
   \node[state,minimum size=3ex]                     (1)   [right =of 0]          {1};
   \node[state,accepting,minimum size=3ex]           (2)   [right =of 1]          {2/0};




  \path[->]      (0)  edge     [loop above]   node           {a:a / 1.2}   ()
                 (0)  edge      [bend left]   node           {a:b/ 2.3}   (1)
                 (0)  edge      [bend right]   node           {b:a/ 0.51}   (1)
                 (1)  edge      [loop below]  node         {b:b/ 0.92}   ()
                 (1)  edge                    node           {a:a/ 0.51}   (2);

\end{tikzpicture}  


\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt, node distance=2cm, on grid, auto,thick,initial text=,minimum size=0pt]
   \node[state, initial,minimum size=3ex]            (0)                          {0};
   \node[state,minimum size=3ex]                     (1)   [above right =of 0]    {1};
   \node[state,minimum size=3ex]                     (2)   [right =of 0]          {4};
   \node[state,minimum size=3ex]                     (3)   [right =of 2]          {2};
   \node[state,minimum size=3ex,accepting]           (4)   [right =of 3]          {3/0};


\begin{scope}[every node/.style={scale=.7}]
  \path[->]      (0)  edge        node           {a:a / 2.81}   (1)
                 (0)  edge        node           {a:b / 3.91}   (2)
                 (0)  edge     [bend right]   node           {b:a / 0.73}   (3)
                (1)  edge        node           {a:a / 0.51}   (3)
                (2)  edge        node           {a:b / 0.92}   (3)
                (3)  edge       node          {b:a / 1.2}   (4);


  \end{scope}


\end{tikzpicture}   

\end{document}
```

but I want to represent 2 like this and the third before?

[image]

Comment: It's not clear to me what your question is. Can you please elaborate a little more? Also, your example code won't work, you need to add the `positioning` and `automata` libraries.

Comment: Your MWE does not compile for me with TeXLive2011.  Please add the necessary packages to get this to compile.

Comment: Please write a clear question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your question is just about positioning the figures, you could use `minipages` to get them where you want. The output on the left imitates your example, with blank lines in between the `tikzpictures`.  As is the case in normal text, blank lines are treated as a new paragraph.  On the right is the output obtained by wrapping them in a `minipage` to get them where you want:

[image]
[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [fill=yellow] (0,0) rectangle (2,2);
\end{tikzpicture}   

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [fill=brown] (0,0) circle (1cm);
\end{tikzpicture}   

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [fill=cyan] (0,0) -- (2,0) -- (1,2) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}   

\bigskip\hrule\bigskip

\begin{minipage}{0.45\linewidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw [fill=yellow] (0,0) rectangle (2,2);
    \end{tikzpicture}   
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}% Need blank line above
        \draw [fill=brown] (0,0) circle (1cm);
    \end{tikzpicture}   
\end{minipage}
%  No blank line here
\begin{minipage}{0.45\linewidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw [fill=cyan] (0,0) -- (2,0) -- (1,2) -- cycle;
    \end{tikzpicture}   
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The result of tikzpicture environment is a box. You can use something like `\vbox,\hbox`or something in the spirit of LaTeX  : `minipage`

```
\documentclass[openright,a4paper,11pt,french]{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,automata}
\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{7cm}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt, node distance=2cm, on grid, auto,thick,initial text=]
       \node[state, initial,minimum size=3ex]            (0)                          {0};
       \node[state,minimum size=3ex]                     (1)   [above right =of 0]    {1};
       \node[state,minimum size=3ex]                     (2)   [right =of 0]          {2};
       \node[state,accepting,minimum size=3ex]           (3)   [right =of 2]          {3/0};

      \path[->]      (0)  edge               node           {a:a / 1.61}   (1)
                     (0)  edge               node           {b:b/ 0.22}   (2)
                     (1)  edge               node           {a:b/ 0}   (2)
                     (2)  edge [loop below]  node         {b:a/ 0.69}   ()
                     (2)  edge               node           {b:a/ 0.69}   (3);

    \end{tikzpicture}   

    \begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt, node distance=2cm, on grid, auto,thick,initial text=,minimum size=0pt]
       \node[state, initial ,minimum size=3ex]            (0)                          {0};
       \node[state,minimum size=3ex]                     (1)   [right =of 0]          {1};
       \node[state,accepting,minimum size=3ex]           (2)   [right =of 1]          {2/0};

      \path[->]      (0)  edge      [loop above]   node           {a:a / 1.2}   ()
                     (0)  edge      [bend left]    node           {a:b/ 2.3}   (1)
                     (0)  edge      [bend right]   node           {b:a/ 0.51}   (1)
                     (1)  edge      [loop below]   node         {b:b/ 0.92}   ()
                     (1)  edge                     node           {a:a/ 0.51}   (2);

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{7cm}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt, node distance=2cm, on grid, auto,thick,initial text=,minimum size=0pt]
       \node[state, initial,minimum size=3ex]            (0)                          {0};
       \node[state,minimum size=3ex]                     (1)   [above right =of 0]    {1};
       \node[state,minimum size=3ex]                     (2)   [right =of 0]          {4};
       \node[state,minimum size=3ex]                     (3)   [right =of 2]          {2};
       \node[state,minimum size=3ex,accepting]           (4)   [right =of 3]          {3/0};

    \begin{scope}[every node/.style={scale=.7}]
      \path[->]      (0)  edge        node           {a:a / 2.81}   (1)
                     (0)  edge        node           {a:b / 3.91}   (2)
                     (0)  edge     [bend right]   node           {b:a / 0.73}   (3)
                     (1)  edge        node           {a:a / 0.51}   (3)
                     (2)  edge        node           {a:b / 0.92}   (3)
                     (3)  edge        node          {b:a / 1.2}   (4);


      \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image]